# "Avec une condition" et "à une condition"

Tags: usage, prépositions

Quelle est la différence ?

> J'accepte mais **avec** une condition.
>
> J'accepte mais **à** une condition.

Par ailleurs, pourquoi peut-on utiliser **à** ici ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Les deux sont possibles, et il existe aussi *sous une condition*, avec le même sens.

Google NGram montre clairement qu'*à une condition* est beaucoup plus courant.

[image]

On peut utiliser *à* ici car il introduit un complément de manière dans la locution *accepter à une condition*.